# Angular Library - ng-packagr is exporting private component/service/pipe/class

Tags: angular, ng-packagr, angular-library

I'm creating a very big library of components, services, etc., so our organisation can focus only on domain code.

In this library I have some components, service, etc. that must be kept private because they live within a certain context that I control within the library.

When I build the lib, I see a lots of exports from ng-packagr that have been added to my lib.d.ts:

```
export * from './public_api';
export { TrBoutonBase as ɵa } from './lib/bouton/tr-bouton-base';
export { TrNotificationComponent as ɵc } from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/components/tr-notification/tr-notification.component';
export { NotificationMaxContentFilterPipe as ɵb } from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/pipes/notification-max-content-filter.pipe';
export { TrChampDateTexteValeur as ɵd } from './lib/formulaire/components/tr-champ-date/tr-champ-date-texte-valeur';
```

Everything that is from `export * from './public_api` is my public API.

All the other export are from ng-packagr and I would like to hide it from my end-user, because they are still able to use them (albeit with ugly characters but they can use them).

**EDIT**

Content of my public_api.ts

```
// Module Bouton
export * from './lib/bouton/tr-bouton/tr-bouton.component';
export * from './lib/bouton/tr-bouton-lien/tr-bouton-lien.component';
export * from './lib/bouton/tr-bouton-rond/tr-bouton-rond.component';
export * from './lib/bouton/tr-bouton.module';

// Module CommunicationUi
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-message/tr-message.enums';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-message/tr-message.interfaces';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-message/tr-message.service';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-message/tr-message.component';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/enums/tr-notification-type.enum';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/enums/tr-notification-type-animation.enum';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/interfaces/tr-notification-icones';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/interfaces/tr-notification-event';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/interfaces/tr-notification-options';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/interfaces/tr-notification';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/consts/tr-notification-options-token.const';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/consts/tr-notifiaction-icon-par-defaut.const';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/consts/tr-notification-options-par-defaut.const';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/tr-notifications.service';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-notification/components/tr-notifications/tr-notifications.component';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-traitement-en-cours/tr-traitement-en-cours.interfaces';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-traitement-en-cours/tr-traitement-en-cours.service';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-traitement-en-cours/tr-traitement-en-cours.component';
export * from './lib/communication-ui/tr-communication-ui.module';

// Enums
export * from './lib/enums/tr-bootstrap.enums';

// Module Formulaire
export * from './lib/formulaire/components/tr-bloc-controles/tr-bloc-controles.modeles';
export * from './lib/formulaire/components/tr-bloc-controles/tr-bloc-controles.component';
export * from './lib/formulaire/components/tr-champ-date/tr-champ-date.component';
export * from './lib/formulaire/components/tr-champ-lecture-seule/tr-champ-lecture-seule.component';
export * from './lib/formulaire/components/tr-champ-requis/tr-champ-requis.component';
export * from './lib/formulaire/components/tr-controle-form/tr-controle-form.component';
export * from './lib/formulaire/directives/tr-hauteur-automatique/tr-hauteur-auto-textarea.directive';
export * from './lib/formulaire/guards/tr-page-avec-formulaire.guard';
export * from './lib/formulaire/validators/tr-dates.validator';
export * from './lib/formulaire/validators/tr-form-array.validator';
export * from './lib/formulaire/validators/tr-regex.validator';
export * from './lib/formulaire/tr-form.service';
export * from './lib/formulaire/tr-form.module';

// Helpers
export * from './lib/helpers/date/tr-date.helper';

// Module Mise en Page
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-menu-contextuel/tr-menu-contextuel.service';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-menu-pied-page/tr-menu-pied-page.enums';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-menu-pied-page/tr-menu-pied-page.interfaces';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-menu-pied-page/tr-menu-pied-page.service';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-menu-pied-page/tr-menu-pied-page.component';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-message-banniere/tr-message-banniere.component';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-modal/tr-modal.component';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-modal-pied/tr-modal-pied.component';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-sections-extensibles/tr-section-extenstensible.service';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-sections-extensibles/tr-section-extensible/tr-section-extensible.component';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-sections-extensibles/tr-section-extensible-groupe/tr-section-extensible-groupe.component';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-titre-page/tr-titre-page.component';
export * from './lib/mise-en-page/tr-mise-en-page.module';

// Module Navigation
export * from './lib/navigation/tr-navigation.interfaces';
export * from './lib/navigation/tr-menu-horizontal/tr-menu-horizontal.component';
export * from './lib/navigation/tr-piv-bas-page/tr-piv-bas-page.component';
export * from './lib/navigation/tr-piv-entete/tr-piv-entete.component';
export * from './lib/navigation/tr-retour-haut-page/tr-retour-haut-page.component';
export * from './lib/navigation/tr-navigation.module';

// Module Pipes
export * from './lib/pipes/tr-afficher-sauts-lignes/tr-afficher-sauts-lignes';
export * from './lib/pipes/tr-pipes.module';

// Module Services
export * from './lib/services/tr-historique/tr-historique.service';
export * from './lib/services/tr-valeurs-service/tr-valeurs.consts';
export * from './lib/services/tr-valeurs-service/tr-valeurs.interfaces';
export * from './lib/services/tr-valeurs-service/tr-valeurs.service';
export * from './lib/services/tr-services.module';

// Module MCO
export * from './lib/tr-mco.module';
```

Comment: can you share `public_api` content?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, did you solved your problem ?

Comment: For now, we decided to expose everything as public and in the code review we check if someone use thoses.

Comment: @Vince i am facing issue while importing the module which was generated by ng-packagr could you please help me